# How do I use numpy.genfromtxt to read a lower triagular matrix into a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a lower diagonal matrix like this

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
```

in a text file, and I want to read it into a numpy array with zeros above the main diagonal. The simplest code I can think of

```
import io
import scipy

data = "1\n2 3\n4 5 6"
scipy.genfromtxt(io.BytesIO(data.encode()))
```

fails with

```
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #2 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
    Line #3 (got 3 columns instead of 1)
```

which makes sense, because in the text file, there isn't *anything* in the upper diagonal part of the matrix, so numpy doesn't know what to interpret as missing values.

Looking at the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), I want something like the `invalid_raise = False` option, except I don't want to skip the "invalid" rows.

---

With some modifications from the answer below, the final code I'm using is

```
import scipy

with open("data.txt", "r") as r:
    data = r.read()
    n = data.count("\n") + 1
    mat = scipy.zeros((n, n))
    mat[scipy.tril_indices_from(mat)] = data.split()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.tril_indices_from()` makes it easy to populate your array lower-triagular matrix through fancy idexing:

```
data = "1\n2 3\n4 5 6"
n = len(data.split('\n'))
data = data.replace('\n', ' ').split()

a = np.zeros((n, n))
a[np.tril_indices_from(a)] = data

print(a)
#array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
#       [ 2.,  3.,  0.],
#       [ 4.,  5.,  6.]])
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I used `n = data.count("\n") + 1` instead of splitting the string, but the result is the same. Also, you don't need to replace newlines before splitting, because `string.split()` without arguments splits on all whitespace characters. See my answer for the code I ended up using.